# Possible time web service operations

Tags: web-services, time

In our client application we need to get the time of the server. For this getTime() operation added to an existing web service on server which basically returns DateTime.Now (.Net environment). 
At the moment there seems no other time related need other than current time. 
But what methods can be added beside this? If you had such an experience or if you had to add some other methods later, please share your experience.

Note: I know, we can stick to [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI), but I want to know what other needs people face related to time web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timezone information? (i.e. the timezone that the server is situated in..)

Comment: yes, that is a good point. timezone opened a new door that led to many possible web operations (getServerTimeZone, convertToServerTime etc...) thanks.